# Entity Framework won't allow me to compare old value to new value in PUT operation

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api2

I have an ApiController that uses Entity Framework/LINQ to SQL for data access. For a PUT operation I am passing in a "Theme" object which has a string property "Path" which I need to inspect to see if has changed from what is currently in the database. If it has changed, I need to perform an additional action of changing the name of a directory.

I wrote some code to detect this, putting it after checking the ModelState.IsValid property and setting the entry's state to EntityState.Modified. When I was testing it I did not see the behavior I was expecting. I used LINQ to find the current record using the passed-in ID and the value of the property showed the same value as the same property of the object I passed in. As a result, the expression in my if statement evaluates to false and the additional action doesn't occur. However, when I use SQL Management Studio to query the database, the value of the field I'm using in the comparison is what I was expecting.

I've tried getting the current value by calling a separate method that returns a string but I get the same result. If I do this lookup at the beginning of my PUT method, I get an InvalidOperationException:

> Attaching an entity of type 'DataAccess.Models.Theme' failed because
>   another entity of the same type already has the same primary key
>   value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the
>   state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the
>   graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities
>   are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In
>   this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track
>   the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or
>   'Modified' as appropriate.

Here's my code:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutTheme(int id, Theme theme)
{
    if (theme == null)
        return BadRequest();

    if (theme.ID != id)
        return BadRequest();

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
      return BadRequest(ModelState);

    _db.Entry(theme).State = EntityState.Modified;

    // We need to detect whether the theme path changed, and if so, we need to rename the theme folder
    var previousTheme = await _db.Themes.FindAsync(id);

    // We can't do this because the Path property will match the Path value of the passed-in theme
    if ((previousTheme != null) && (theme.Path != previousTheme.Path))
      RenameThemeDirectory(id, previousTheme.Path, theme.Path);

    // Remaining code to save data here
}
```

How can I do this without passing into my method the original Path property value to be used in the comparison?

Comment: What is the purpose of setting the entry state to `EntityState.Modified`? If you comment out that line, does it behave differently?

Comment: I think you're confusing EF by setting the entry state of `theme`, because that has the same primary key ID as the object you pull out of the database later.

Comment: *I've tried getting the current value by calling a separate method that returns a string but I get the same result* I doubt. Something like `var previousPath = await _db.Themes.Where(t => t.Id == id).Select(t => t.Path).FirstAsync();` should give you the information needed from the db w/o side effects.

Comment: My code is based on the scaffolded code from Visual Studio. I believe this tells the database to perform an UPDATE statement instead of an INSERT. I commented out the code and my directory rename operation succeeded but the database record didn't get updated with the new value.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev, you are right... I tried doing something similar but instead of getting the path value I was getting the theme and then using the theme's path property. Thank you!